# Convert variously formatted dates to mysql DATE format to save in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, varchar

Ok, so I have a bit of a mystery on my hands.  I hve a bunch of dates in all different, mostly American, formats.  I need to add them to a mysql database in a DATE field.  So I wrote the blow code to take whatever divider they had and replace it with a hyphen and then used strtotime in conjunction with the date function to convert it to the right format.  I thought I would be home free, but no.

```
$q = "SELECT date_rendered, date_requested, record_id FROM client_svc_history";
$r = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $record_id = $row['record_id'];
    echo $record_id.": ".$row['date_rendered']."  ";
    $date_rendered = preg_replace('~[^0-9]~','-',$row['date_rendered']);
    echo $date_rendered." ";
    $date_rendered = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_rendered));
    echo $date_rendered."<br> ";
    echo $record_id.": ".$row['date_requested']." ";
    $date_requested = preg_replace('~[^0-9]~','-',$row['date_requested']);
    echo $date_requested." ";
    $date_requested = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_requested));
    echo $date_requested."<br>";
}
```

I echo'ed out the data so I could make sure it was working properly before I used it to write back to the database.

Below is a sampling of the output I got.  Notice that in record 7 it took 03-23-2006 and zero'ed it out.  In record 8 it handled the same format with no problem, down in records 11, 12 & 13 it zero'ed out 2 more formats that I thought strtotime could handle.  I am at a loss.  I appreciate any help.  Thanks.

```
1: 0000-00-00 0000-00-00 1969-12-31
1: 2005-02-25 2005-02-25 2005-02-25
2: 0000-00-00 0000-00-00 1969-12-31
2: 0000-00-00 0000-00-00 1969-12-31
3: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
3: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
4: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
4: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
5: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
5: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
6: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
6: 2005-03-08 2005-03-08 2005-03-08
7: 03-23-2006 03-23-2006 1969-12-31
7: 03-23-2006 03-23-2006 1969-12-31
8: 04-10-2006 04-10-2006 2006-10-04
8: 04-10-2006 04-10-2006 2006-10-04
9: 04-10-2006 04-10-2006 2006-10-04
9: 04-11-2006 04-11-2006 2006-11-04
10: 2/10/2006 2-10-2006 2006-10-02
10: 02-10-2006 02-10-2006 2006-10-02
11: 11/29/2005 11-29-2005 1969-12-31
11: 11-29-2005 11-29-2005 1969-12-31
12: 11/29/2005 11-29-2005 1969-12-31
12: 11-29-2005 11-29-2005 1969-12-31
13: 01-26-06 01-26-06 1969-12-31
13: 01-26-2006 01-26-2006 1969-12-31
```

Comment: What are the data types of date_rendered and date_requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime()` won't be able to render accurately string dates that contain `-` in them, because it will try to deduct the time from the current timestamp (e.g. `-1 day`...). Try replacing hyphens `-` with a slash `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [PHP Supported date formats.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) . Convert the date to any of these formats.

Comment: ok, so clearly I am up too late working on this thing.  I Combined 2 different formats.  Thank you :)  Now off to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Dump to a file, sed s/-/// ./dump.txt

Iterate over the file, splitting each date from a string into an array, and run strtotime() on it.